# Extracting node reference ID using minidom in Python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am using minidom in Python and I would like to search through a list of nodes (book) and for each book node where the attribute "name" is equal to "statistics", I want to print the node reference. Here is an example of an XML-file that I would like to process:

```
<book id='123'>
    <name>statistics</name>
</book>

<book id='234'>
    <name>mathematics</name>
</book>

<book id='345'>
    <name>statistics</name>
</book>
```

Desired output is:

```
123
345
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Iterate through each node, testing to see if that node contains the name "statistics", save the id.

Comment: You've picked an XML library to use, but you're not demonstrating any use of it in your question.  It's more helpful if you post valid XML fragments.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've tried to do, but I haven't managed to save the id. Would you happen to know how this can be done?

Comment: Information like this is trivially obtained using [tag:xpath]. E.g. `book[./name/text()="statistics"]/@id`. You'd have to use a library that supports `XPATH`. E.g. [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the book elements and look at the name node to see if its statistics. If it is print out the attribute of the book node, the id.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
Document = "<books>\
            <book id='123'>\
                <name>statistics</name>\
            </book>\
            <book id='234'>\
                <name>mathematics</name>\
            </book>\
            <book id='345'>\
                <name>statistics</name>\
            </book></books>"

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(Document)
for book in dom.getElementsByTagName("book"):
   node = book.getElementsByTagName("name")[0] 
   if node.firstChild.data.strip().lower() == "statistics":
        print int(book.getAttribute("id").strip())
```

Outputs

```
123
345
```

Comment: My post is sadly lacking syntax coloring. What did I do wrong?